# If a function integrates to zero against every even function, then it is odd

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm in the process of figuring this one out as well:

Let $f : [−1, 1] \to\mathbb R$ be a smooth function. Show that if
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)v(x)dx = 0 $$
for every smooth function $v : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ for which $v(x) = v(−x)$, then $f(x) = −f(−x)$ for all $x \in [−1, 1]$.

Not sure where to begin. Where can I go with $ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)v(x)dx = 0 $ and $v(x) = v(−x)$? Reminds me of even and odd.

Comment: If $v:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, how can you talk about $v(-x)$?

Comment: I suspect that the limits on the integral and the interval over which $v$ is defined must both be from $-1$ rather than $0$.

Answer (score 4):

By hypothesis
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\int_{-1}^1f(x)\overbrace{\left(\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2\right)}^{\text{even function}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2\right)\left(\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2\right)\left(\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac14\int_{-1}^1\left(f(x)^2-f(-x)^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2=0
$$
and thus
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2\\
&=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2
\end{align}
$$
which is an odd function.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming user164587's comment is correct:)

Let $g$ be an arbitrary smooth function, and consider $v(x)=g(x)+g(-x)$. We have
\begin{eqnarray}
0&=&\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\left(g(x)+g(-x)\right)dx\\
&=& \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x) \, dx + \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(-x)\, dx \\
&=& \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x) \, dx + \int_{-1}^1 f(-x)g(x)\, dx\\
&=& \int_{-1}^1 g(x) \left(f(x)+f(-x)\right)dx \, .
\end{eqnarray}

Since this holds for any smooth $g$,  $f(x)+f(-x)$ is identically zero and so $f$ is odd.

Comment: Nice answer - short and simple!

Comment: Why can we conclude that f(x) + f(-x) is zero when it is in the integral?

Comment: @KevinCarroll: Because $g$ was arbitrary. If $\phi$ is a sufficiently nice (say, continuous) function such that $\int \phi g=0$ for *every* smooth function $g$, then $\phi$ must be identically zero on the domain of integration.

Comment: (Although, it occurs to me that the easy proof of this when $\phi$ is smooth is "let $g=\phi$", at which point my answer basically reduces to robjohn's...)

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a slicker way to do this, but here's the brute-force method. Suppose there is some $x > 0$ for which $f(x) \neq -f(-x)$. Without loss of generality, say $f(x) > -f(-x)$. Then this is still true on some small interval $I$ around $x$, by continuity. Construct $g$ to be $1$ on $I$ and $-I$, and zero elsewhere; this is clearly even. Then

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x) = 0$$

which means that the integral of $f$ over $I$, plus the integral of $f(-x)$ over $-I$, is equal to zero. But this is impossible, because $f(x) > -f(-x)$ on $I$.